# How configure c3p0 with Hibernate and JNDI?

Tags: java, hibernate, jndi, c3p0, geronimo

I have an application deployed in geronimo server and use Hibernate framework. I integrated the C3P0 library with it and it works perfectly when i foxed the database url in hibernate.cfg.xml like this:

```xml
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@iddfrvexa.grouperci.com:1574:IDDFRV</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">iqa</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">iqaadmin</property>
<!-- <property name="connection.datasource">java:comp/env/rci_cdofr/jdbc/Datasource</property> -->
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">false</property>
<property name="max_fetch_depth">0</property>
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.factory_class">net.bull.javamelody.HibernateBatcherFactory</property>

<!-- <property name="hibernate.dbcp.validationQuery">SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</property> 
     <property name="hibernate.dbcp.testOnBorrow">true</property> -->

<!-- c3p0 config http://www.hibernate.org/214.html -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="c3p0.max_size">20</property>
<property name="c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
<property name="c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
```

but when i use jndi like this :

```xml
<property name="connection.datasource">java:comp/env/rci_cdofr/jdbc/Datasource</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">false</property>
<property name="max_fetch_depth">0</property>

<property name="hibernate.jdbc.factory_class">net.bull.javamelody.HibernateBatcherFactory</property>

<!-- c3p0 config http://www.hibernate.org/214.html -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="c3p0.max_size">20</property>
<property name="c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
<property name="c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name = "c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
```

the c3p0 does not work and an error has been appeared.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2009)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1292)
    at com.rcibanque.framework.persistance.hibernate.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:45)
    at com.rcibanque.framework.persistance.hibernate.HibernateTransaction.begin(HibernateTransaction.java:62)
    at com.rcibanque.common.application.ReferencesService.loadReferences(ReferencesService.java:52)
    at com.rcibanque.common.start.InitServlet.init(InitServlet.java:46)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4413)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext.access$201(GeronimoStandardContext.java:63)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext$SystemMethodValve.invoke(GeronimoStandardContext.java:398)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.invoke(GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.java:47)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext.start(GeronimoStandardContext.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.TomcatContainer.addContext(TomcatContainer.java:369)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.TomcatWebAppContext.doStart(TomcatWebAppContext.java:512)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.createInstance(GBeanInstance.java:998)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.attemptFullStart(GBeanInstanceState.java:268)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.start(GBeanInstanceState.java:102)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.start(GBeanInstance.java:541)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency.attemptFullStart(GBeanDependency.java:111)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency.addTarget(GBeanDependency.java:146)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency$1.running(GBeanDependency.java:120)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor.fireRunningEvent(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:176)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor.access$300(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:44)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor$RawLifecycleBroadcaster.fireRunningEvent(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:254)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.attemptFullStart(GBeanInstanceState.java:294)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.start(GBeanInstanceState.java:102)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.startRecursive(GBeanInstanceState.java:124)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.startRecursive(GBeanInstance.java:555)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.startRecursiveGBean(BasicKernel.java:379)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.ConfigurationUtil.startConfigurationGBeans(ConfigurationUtil.java:456)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.ConfigurationUtil.startConfigurationGBeans(ConfigurationUtil.java:493)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.KernelConfigurationManager.start(KernelConfigurationManager.java:188)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.startConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:563)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.startConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:544)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.ReflectionMethodInvoker.invoke(ReflectionMethodInvoker.java:34)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanOperation.invoke(GBeanOperation.java:124)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.invoke(GBeanInstance.java:867)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.invoke(BasicKernel.java:239)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.KernelGBean.invoke(KernelGBean.java:342)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor163.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.ReflectionMethodInvoker.invoke(ReflectionMethodInvoker.java:34)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanOperation.invoke(GBeanOperation.java:124)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.invoke(GBeanInstance.java:867)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.invoke(BasicKernel.java:239)
    at org.apache.geronimo.system.jmx.MBeanGBeanBridge.invoke(MBeanGBeanBridge.java:172)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1427)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor150.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    ... 82 more
```

and when i debug i found that the database url was null.
Can anyone help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer below , you cannot really wrap a server resource , that not the main idea. Imagine that in case every App was able to wrap that , then again why you need a shared resource from the first place. So maybe you have to re-consider the overall flow and properly configure the datasource pooling on server's config. Also note that your first example is working , because your Application simply define its own datasource and does not depend on server's resources.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that if you want to wrap an existing JNDI datasource with a c3p0-pooled version, you'll have to build that DataSource yourself in Java, and then configure Hibernate to look for that `DataSource`'s JNDI name. I don't think hibernate supports wrapping an existing `DataSource` in a c3p0 pool via configuration of its `ConnectionProvider`.

The Java side of wrapping an unpooled DataSource is really [easy in c3p0](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#using_datasources_factory). Just acquire a reference to your existing unpooled `DataSource`, and use that in place of `ds_unpooled`.